# MySQL: Is there an issue when using two or more duplicate WHERE clauses?

Tags: mysql

Is there a problem, issue, or performance hit when using duplicate WHERE clauses?

Example SQL code:

```
SELECT *  FROM `table`
WHERE `field` = 1
AND `field` = 1
AND `field2` = 22
AND `field2` = 22
```

Does the optimizer eliminate the duplicates?

Comment: My magic eight ball says "it depends." You can't realistically *not* use complex `WHERE` clauses though.

Comment: I've retagged your question as [mysql], since SQL proper doesn't use backticks in this way. Please correct if I've guessed wrong.

Comment: Looks like your change was unintentionally overwritten, @ruakh, so I've put it back.

Comment: @ruakh It's not really a MySQL-specific question though, it merely happens to use MySQL idiosyncratic syntax to demonstrate the same "problem".

Comment: Yes, y'all are correct: MySQL v5.5.

Comment: @millimoose: Isn't it? The question asks (among other things) about whether there's a performance hit, or whether the optimizer eliminates the duplicates. Those aren't questions about SQL, they're questions about a SQL implementation. Since the OP's SQL implementation is MySQL, that makes this a question about MySQL. No?

Comment: The query with redundant clauses will take an infinitesimally longer time to compile and any affect on the performance will be unnoticeable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `WHERE` clause works like an if condition in any programming language. This clause is used to compare given value with the field value available in MySQL table.

If given value from outside is equal to the available field value in MySQL table, then it returns that row.

You won't face any problems or issues by having duplicate conditions but in a bigger scale this might slightly decrease performance.

EDIT:

You can issue an `EXPLAIN` statement, which tells MySQL to display some information about how it would execute a `SELECT` query without actually executing it. 
This way you can see exactly what is going to be executed.
To use `EXPLAIN`, just put the word `EXPLAIN` in front of the `SELECT` statement:

mysql> `EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM table WHERE 0\G`

```
*************************** 1. row ***************************
id: 1
select_type: SIMPLE
table: NULL
type: NULL
possible_keys: NULL
key: NULL
key_len: NULL
ref: NULL
rows: NULL
Extra: Impossible WHERE
```

Normally, EXPLAIN returns more information than that, including non-NULL information about the indexes that will be used to scan tables, the types of joins that will be used, and estimates of the number of rows that will need to be examined from each table.

Comment: Thx for this nice explanation. Do you think the optimizer removes the duplicates before running the query?

Comment: @user2624632 You can use [`EXPLAIN`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/explain.html) and compare the query plans.